# HTAccess file on wordpress is not redirecting correctly

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I have this in my wordpress htaccess... trying to redirect tp https, and from our .ca to .net domain.  Not working :(.  I am repeating the bottom lines for all of my pages, yet it goes to 401

```
RewriteOptions inherit

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mywebsite\.ca$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mywebsite\.ca$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/(?:\ Ballot169)?
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "http\:\/\/mywebsite\.net\/$1" [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.*$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/(?:\ Ballot169)?
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "http\:\/\/mywebsite\.net\/$1" [R=301,L]


redirect 301 /product-category/concentrates/ http://www.mywebsite.net/product-category/concentrates/
```

Comment: Where are the rest of your WordPress directives? What directives are you inheriting with the `RewriteOptions` directive?

Comment: Oh man, I literally don't know what that means, pretty sure i just pasted this into HTaccess

Comment: Do your `.ca` and `.net` domains point to different sites or do they both point to the same place? You presumably do have other directives in your `.htaccess` file? "i just pasted this into HTaccess" - ???

Comment: "I am repeating the bottom lines for all of my pages" - Errrm, why? What do you _think_ that is doing? Is this the `.htaccess` file for the `.ca` domain only (not WordPress)?

Comment: Nope, we are moving the .ca to .net, and i am trying to direct the main domain, and all our old pages (because we have a big index and I want to maintain SEO equity) to the new domain which links are all the same but .ca is now .net.  I wasn't really sure how to do this and I just copy and pasted a template and this is what I had -  i literally don't understand what any of this is doing TBH!

Comment: So, do the `.ca` and `.net` domains currently point to the same place or different servers?

Comment: .ca is currently directed to .net, but only the home page, the others 404*

Comment: No, where do the domains resolve to? Before the redirection. Do they resolve to the same place? Otherwise it looks like your existing directives would create redirect loops?!

Comment: Nope, we had a website on hosting for the .ca, so i would imagine it is pointing to its own hosting

Answer (score 0):

By the sounds of it, the `.ca` and `.net` domains currently resolve to different vhosts. In which case all you need is the following in the root `.htaccess` file on the `.ca` domain:

```
Redirect 302 / https://www.example.net/
```

...and delete everything else! You don't need any of your existing (100s of) directives - they all repeat the same thing anyway!?

The `Redirect` directive is prefix-matching, so it redirects `/<anything>` (on the `.ca` domain) to `https://www.example.net/<anything>`.

> ```
> RewriteOptions inherit
> ```

Where did this come from? If you simply copy/pasted it from somewhere else then delete it!